# ANTLR on a noisy data stream

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, noise-words

I'm very new in the ANTLR world and I'm trying to figure out how can I use this parsing tool to interpret a set of "noisy" string. What I would like to achieve is the following. 

let's take for example this phrase : `It's 10PM and the Lazy CAT is currently SLEEPING heavily on the SOFA in front of the TV`

What I would like to extract is `CAT`, `SLEEPING` and `SOFA` and have a grammar that match easily the following pattern : SUBJECT - VERB - INDIRECT OBJECT... where I could define 
`VERB : 'SLEEPING' | 'WALKING';`
`SUBJECT : 'CAT'|'DOG'|'BIRD';`
`INDIRECT_OBJECT : 'CAR'| 'SOFA';`

etc.. I don't want to ends up with a permanent "NoViableException" as I can't describe all the possibilities around the language structure. I just want to tear apart useless words and just keep the one that are interesting.

 It's more like if I had a tokeniser and asked the parser "Ok, read the stream until you find a SUBJECT, then ignore the rest until you find a VERB, etc.."

I need to extract an organized structure in an un-organized set... For example, I would like to be able to interpret (I'm not judging the pertinence of this utterly basic and incorrect view of 'english grammar')  
`SUBJECT - VERB - INDIRECT OBJECT`
`INDIRECT OBJECT - SUBJECT - VERB` 
 
so I will parse sentences like 
`It's 10PM and the Lazy CAT is currently SLEEPING heavily on the SOFA in front of the TV` 
or
 `It's 10PM and, on the SOFA in front of the TV,  the Lazy CAT is currently SLEEPING heavily`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create only a couple of lexer rules (the ones you posted, for example), and as a last lexer rule, you could match any character and `skip()` it:

```
VERB            : 'SLEEPING' | 'WALKING';
SUBJECT         : 'CAT'|'DOG'|'BIRD';
INDIRECT_OBJECT : 'CAR'| 'SOFA';
ANY             : . {skip();};
```

The order is important here: the lexer tries to match tokens from top to bottom, so if it can't match any of the tokens `VERB`, `SUBJECT` or `INDIRECT_OBJECT`, it "falls through" to the `ANY` rule and skips this token. You can then use these parser rules to filter your input stream:

```
parse
  :  sentenceParts+ EOF
  ;

sentenceParts
  :  SUBJECT VERB INDIRECT_OBJECT
  ;
```

which will parse the input text:

> *It's 10PM and the Lazy CAT is currently SLEEPING* 
>   *heavily on the SOFA in front of the TV. The DOG* 
>   *is WALKING on the SOFA.*

as follows:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to achieve ! This is way more intuitive than JavaCC on dealing with that kind of filter