# ANTLR on a noisy data stream Part 2

Tags: antlr, grammar, noise-words

Following a very interesing discussion with Bart Kiers [on parsing a noisy datastream with ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310699/antlr-on-a-noisy-data-stream), I'm ending up with another problem...

The aim is still the same : only extracting useful information with the following grammar,

```
VERB            : 'SLEEPING' | 'WALKING';
SUBJECT         : 'CAT'|'DOG'|'BIRD'; 
INDIRECT_OBJECT : 'CAR'| 'SOFA';  
ANY             : . {skip();};

parse 
  :  sentenceParts+ EOF 
  ;

sentenceParts  
  :  SUBJECT VERB INDIRECT_OBJECT  
  ;
```

a sentence like `it's 10PM and the Lazy CAT is currently SLEEPING heavily on the SOFA in front of the TV.` will produce the following

[image]

This is perfect and it's doing exactly what I want.. from a big sentence, I'm extracting only the words that had a sense for me.... But the, I founded the following error. If somewhere in the text I'm introducing a word that begin exactly like a token, I'm ending up with a `MismathedTokenException` or a `noViableException`

```
    it's 10PM and the Lazy CAT is currently SLEEPING heavily, 
    with a DOGGY bag, on the SOFA in front of the TV.
```

produce an error :

[image]

`DOGGY` is interpreted as the beginning for `DOG` which is also a part of the TOKEN `SUBJECT` and the lexer is lost... How could I avoid this without defining `DOGGY` as a special token... I would have like the parser to understand `DOGGY` as a word in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that adding this `ANY2 :'A'..'Z'+ {skip();};` solves my problem !