# ANTLR on a noisy data stream Part 3

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, text-parsing

Still in the process of learning ANTLR... Recently I have been posting 2 questions regarding parsing some text and extracting information leaving aside "unwanted" words or character. Following a very interesing discussion with Bart Kiers [on parsing a noisy datastream Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310699/antlr-on-a-noisy-data-stream) and  [and parsing a noisy datastream Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325011/antlr-on-a-noisy-data-stream-part-2), I'm ending up with one more problem...

Originally, my grammar looks like this

```
VERB            : 'SLEEPING' | 'WALKING';
SUBJECT         : 'CAT'|'DOG'|'BIRD'; 
INDIRECT_OBJECT : 'CAR'| 'SOFA';
ANY2            :'A'..'Z'+ {skip();};
ANY             : . {skip();};

parse 
  :  sentenceParts+ EOF 
  ;

sentenceParts  
  :  SUBJECT VERB INDIRECT_OBJECT  
  ;
```

a sentence like `it's 10PM and the Lazy CAT is currently SLEEPING heavily on the SOFA in front of the TV.` will produce the following

[image]

This is good... and it does what I want, i.e. extracting only the word `CAT`, `SLEEPING` and `SOFA`, leaving aside other words. Now, for another reason, I need to introduce a new token in my grammar, let's call it `OTHER : 'PLANE'`. It will be used later by another rule. I still want my primary rule to work : `SUBJECT VERB INDIRECT_OBJECT`. Let's say the token `'PLANE'` appears in my sentence, like

`it's 10PM and the Lazy CAT on the PLANE is currently SLEEPING heavily on the SOFA in front of the TV.` It will produce the following error (no surprise here as the lexer has a clear definition of 'PLANE' as a token) 
[image]

Is there a way to tell ANTLR that if I'm entering the rule `sentenceParts` I only care about the 3 tokens I have defined, namely `SUBJECT`, `VERB` or `INDIRECT_OBJECT` and that, even if it comes across a different token, not to take it into account ? I would like to be able to do that without putting `OTHER?` everywhere in this rule

Answer (score 1):

Well in fact, I might have found a way to do it... Although it's questionable at that point to introduce tokens if you don't want to parse them, this solution works :

```
VERB            : 'SLEEPING' | 'WALKING';
SUBJECT         : 'CAT'|'DOG'|'BIRD'; 
INDIRECT_OBJECT : 'CAR'| 'SOFA';
OTHER       : 'PLANE';
OTHER2      : 'BEAUTIFUL';
OTHER3      : 'HEAVILLY';
ANY2            :'A'..'Z'+ {skip();};
ANY             : . {skip();};
```

parse 
  :  sentenceParts+ EOF 
  ;

next    :   ( options {greedy=false;}: .)*;

sentenceParts
  :  SUBJECT next VERB next INDIRECT_OBJECT
  ;

this will produce on the following sentence `it's 10PM and the Lazy CAT on the BEAUTIFUL PLANE is currently SLEEPING HEAVILLY on the SOFA in front of the TV` the following tree... So that intermediary token
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a bit of a strange approach. Note that it doesn't really matter if you put a couple of `next`'s in your rules instead `OTHER?`'s. To be honest, I think it's all rather messy. Perhaps you could explain what you're really trying to do here, since I get the impression you're only explaining a very simplified version of your real problem.

Comment: Hi Bart, you're absolutely right. As you said, I'm running a more complex problem. I'm doing some research on the medical field and to screen through different reports. The problem being, the are no real structures in the files. I need to catch some very specific patern like "Patient X, age 45, is having difficulty with bla bla bla and cholesterol amount is 0.65-0.85 per ml/ blood.." etc. Obvioulsy there is a lot of number and messy data I don't care. I just want to ends up with AGE, CHOLESTEROL, 0.65-0.85... But I will tokenize all other numbers or key token in an unorganized way...

Comment: Hmm, that's going to be tricky. You might want to google a bit for existing NLP parsers. If you're comfortable with it, you could also post a couple of difficult "real world" examples you've encountered so far, or at least something very close to it: perhaps I (or someone else) can suggest something better suited than the road you're now walking (which is not going to be very fruitful IMO). Best of luck!

Comment: Will try to provide some real example. Just one quick question, is it possible to define 2 different lexers and use them within one grammar ? Thanks

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You might want to look at the "island grammar" wiki entry though: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Island+Grammars+Under+Parser+Control

Comment: Thanks Bart, I will have a look to this

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell ANTLR that if I'm entering the rule sentenceParts I only care about the 3 tokens I have defined, namely SUBJECT, VERB or INDIRECT_OBJECT and that, even if it comes across a different token, not to take it into account ? I would like to be able to do that without putting OTHER? everywhere in this rule

No.

You either ignore the token, or you don't, in which case you'll have to make it optional in your parser rule(s).